# Calculations in module / While Loop / Transferring Variables

Tags: python, loops

I'm very new to python and I'm stuck in some basic problems.

1. I can't seem to be able to put most of my calculations in a module. If I do, the results are not transferable and they will always show up as 0.0.
2. Once I'm able to put my calculations in a module, I can put the module inside a loop and ask the user if he wants to repeat the action.
3. This is my main issue too :: I want to "store" the output (displayResults) of each of the items (item number, price, etc) and print all of them once the loop is cancelled.

Thanks! I'm having a pretty difficult time trying to figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
#Mateo Marquez
#Oct. 8th, 2012
#P.O.S information system assigment
#

#Define Global Variables
TAX = 0.6
YELLOW_TAG = 0.10
BLUE_TAG = 0.20
RED_TAG = 0.25
GREEN_TAG = 0

#Main Module
def main():

    tax_fee = 0.0
    total_price = 0.0
    introUser()

    # I want this to be the mainCalc() function and return results.

    productNumber=raw_input("Please enter the Product Number: ")
    cost=float(raw_input("Please enter the cost of the selected product: "))
        print " "
        print "As you might have noticed, our discounts are color coded"
        print "Yellow is 10%, Blue is 20% & Red is 25%"
        print " "
    tagDiscount=raw_input("Please enter the color tag: (yellow, blue, red or none)")
    if tagDiscount == 'yellow':
        print " "
        print "You get a 10% discount"
        total_price = (YELLOW_TAG*cost)
    if tagDiscount == 'blue':
        print " "
        print "You get a 20% discount"
        total_price = (BLUE_TAG*cost)
    if tagDiscount == 'red':
        print " "
        print "You get a 25% discount"
        total_price = (RED_TAG*cost)
    if tagDiscount == 'none':
        print " "
        print "No discount for you!"
        total_price = 0

    print " "
    print "~Remember~ this weekend is Tax Free in most of the country"
    print "Green Tags designate if the product is tax free"
    tagDiscount=raw_input("Does your product has a Green Tag? (yes or no)")
    if tagDiscount == 'yes':
        print " "
        print "Good! your product is tax free"
        tax_fee = 0
    if tagDiscount == 'no':
        print " "
        print "I'm sorry, product", productNumber, "requires regular tax"
        tax_fee = (TAX*total_price)

#I want this to be the end of the mainCalc() function       

displayResults(total_price, tax_fee, cost, productNumber)

#Introduction function
def introUser():
    print "Welcome to Wannabee's"
    print "I'll gladly help you with your price question"
    print "Let's start"
    print " " 


#Display results function
def displayResults(total_price, tax_fee, cost, productNumber):
    print " "
    print "Your Product Number: ", productNumber
    print "Listed price of your product: $", cost
    print "Your discount: $", total_price
    print "Your Tax amount: $", tax_fee
    print "Your grand total: $", (cost - total_price - tax_fee)
    print " "
    print "Your savings: ", ((cost-total_price)/cost*100),"%!"

main()
```

Comment: Firstly, please fix your indentation. Secondly, I'm not sure what you mean by "module": in Python, a module is a .py file, but you seem to be using it to mean "function".

Comment: Yes, I meant function.

I want to include my main calculations into a "def mainCalc ()" so it looks more organize and I can call it easier. If I do this, the results of all that are not displayed in the displayResults()

Comment: plz fix your indentation, it's almost impossible to read the way it is now

Comment: Ok! I'm in the process of it! Sorry - I'm trying the best I can!

Answer (score 0):

In order to save values used by related routines, put the variables and the routines that use them in a class.  The following code defines a "POS" class and two method routines that share its variables.  The "self." notation in the methods indicates a class variable that is saved in the instance "p" that is created when the class is instantiated with `p = POS()`.

The example illustrates how the variables are stored; you'll need to adjust the inputs and print statements as needed (they're in Python 3 here).  If you want to store the items as they are input and print them at the end, create an empty list in `__init__`, add a tuple to the list in `mainCalc()`, and print out each of the list items in `displayResults()`.

```
class POS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.taxrate = 0.06
        self.disc = {"": 0.0, "yellow": 0.10, "blue": 0.20, "red": 0.25}
        self.total = 0
        self.savings = 0
        self.tax = 0

    def mainCalc(self, item, qty, cost, tag, taxable):
        print(qty, "* Item", item, "@ ${:.2f}".format(cost),
                                   "= ${:.2f}".format(qty*cost))
        discount = cost * self.disc[tag]
        if (tag):
            print("  You get a", int(100*self.disc[tag]),
                  "% discount ${:.2f}".format(discount), "for", tag, "tag")
        self.total += qty * (cost - discount)
        self.savings += discount
        if (taxable == "yes"):
            tax = qty * cost * self.taxrate
            self.tax += tax
            print("  tax ${:.2f}".format(tax))
        else:
            print("  tax free")

    def displayResults(self):
        print("----------------")
        print("Your total:     ${:.2f}".format(self.total))
        print("Your savings:   ${:.2f}".format(self.savings))
        print("Your total tax: ${:.2f}".format(self.tax))
        print("Grand total:    ${:.2f}".format(self.total + self.tax))
        return

p = POS()

#        Item  Qty Price  Tag      Taxable
items = [(1492, 1, 1.95, "yellow", "yes"),
         (1524, 2, 4.50, "blue",   "no"),
         (2843, 1, 6.95, "blue",   "yes"),
         (1824, 3, 2.29, "",       "yes")]

for i in items:
    p.mainCalc(*i)

p.displayResults()
```

Running the example produces:

> ```
> 1 * Item 1492 @ $1.95 = $1.95
>   You get a 10 % discount $0.20 for yellow tag
>   tax $0.12
> 2 * Item 1524 @ $4.50 = $9.00
>   You get a 20 % discount $0.90 for blue tag
>   tax free
> 1 * Item 2843 @ $6.95 = $6.95
>   You get a 20 % discount $1.39 for blue tag
>   tax $0.42
> 3 * Item 1824 @ $2.29 = $6.87
>   tax $0.41
> ----------------
> Your total:     $21.39
> Your savings:   $2.49
> Your total tax: $0.95
> Grand total:    $22.33
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following constraints:

- A function can only be called **after** it has been defined by a `def` statement (your call to `displayResults`.
- Functions cannot access variables that are defined locally in the body of another function definition.

To improve your code, either think about how the program should flow from an overall point of view, or use a class as suggested in Dave's answer.